# Remove extra particles on side of object with weight paint not working properly?

Tags: particles, weight-painting, hair

So I am trying to add these pieces onto my cylinder shape donut object by using hair particles, then rendering the sprinkle piece as an object so it shows on my donut shape.

Project file here https://pasteall.org/blend/c0527c98b90947ad812ea810a7412eb1

So here is my problem, some pieces fall over the edge and I don't know how to get rid of them because after I cut some hair particles on particle mode, it doesn't allow me to edit it anymore.

[image]

[image: Weight paint is only targeting the top surface]

[image]

[image]

So you can see all the hair particles are perfectly on top only. After I switched to particle mode and cut some loose hairs on the sides, the final image 4 above switches the UI to this and doesn't allow me to change the number of hairs or do any further editing.

So I don't know what else to do to get rid of these pieces on the side without restarting the entire process from scratch and guessing which areas to not weight paint

Comment: if you provide your blend file, i will have a look

Comment: @Chris how do i do that without sending the entire project? only the necessary files?

Comment: just make a copy of your original blend file, open the copy and delete every object which isn't necessary to reproduce your problem. Then upload to dropbox or whatever cloud service you want.

Comment: @Chris  https://pasteall.org/blend/c0527c98b90947ad812ea810a7412eb1 I added it here